# While creating pdf in asp.net facing problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext7

i am using visual studio 2019 with C#.when i try to create a pdf document it is successfully created, but when it is opened by Response method it show error message "Acrobat reader could not open file because it is not supported file type".

```
enter code here
```

[image]

i am using following code.

```
 protected void Exportpdf()
        {
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path+ "\\Appointments" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf");
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
  Paragraph header = new Paragraph("MyTurns.in")
               .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
               .SetFontSize(20);

            // New line
            Paragraph newline = new Paragraph(new Text("\n"));

            document.Add(newline);
            document.Add(header);

            // Add sub-header
            Paragraph subheader = new Paragraph("Appointment List Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"))
               .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
               .SetFontSize(15);
            document.Add(subheader);
 document.Close();
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Appointments" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".pdf");
            Response.Write(document);
           
            Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Well,  I would write out the buffer to a file, and see if you can open it. However, you need to use Respose.BinaryWrite(document) - that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You try to return the generated PDF by writing the `document` object:

```
Response.Write(document);
```

This is wrong because the iText 7 `Document` is merely a facade for adding content to a `PdfDocument` (your object `pdf`) which in turn does not contain the PDF either but writes it out via its `PdfWriter`, in your code to the file at

```
path+ "\\Appointments" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf"
```

Thus, what you should write to the response is the content of this file.

As `DateTime.Now` meanwhile changed, you should generate that path in a variable first and use this variable in both places.

Furthermore, as Albert D. Kallal already commented, it should be written as binary, using `BinaryWrite`.

Alternatively, if you don't actually need the pdf results in the file system, you can use a `MemoryStream` instead of the actual file system file.

---

You indicated in comments and answers that you indeed are not at all interested in the file in the file system. Thus, you should use a `MemoryStream`. You already found example code for using a `MemoryStream` with iText 5. A corresponding example for iText 7 would look like this:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream))
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer))
    using (Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4))
    {
        Paragraph header = new Paragraph("MyTurns.in")
           .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
           .SetFontSize(20);

        // New line
        Paragraph newline = new Paragraph(new Text("\n"));

        document.Add(newline);
        document.Add(header);

        // Add sub-header
        Paragraph subheader = new Paragraph("Appointment List Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"))
           .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
           .SetFontSize(15);
        document.Add(subheader);
    }

    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Appointments" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".pdf");
    Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
}
```

---

By the way, concerning your line

```
Response.End();
```

you should probably read the [ASP.NET documentation of it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end)

> This method is provided only for compatibility with ASP - that is, for compatibility with COM-based Web-programming technology that preceded ASP.NET. If you want to jump ahead to the `EndRequest` event and send a response to the client, it is usually preferable to call `CompleteRequest` instead.

and re-consider its use.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll have some time.

Comment: Wow sir your are so great, its working, Pls mention your complete name, i would like to thank you on my website.This problem has wasted my one week. I am from india from which country your are?